# Replace with regular expression a character with other by index?

Tags: java, regex

Is possible replace a character in String in java, using a specific character from the indice of match.

For example:

I want use some specific map:

a=d , b=e , c=f

Then: a want replace a with d, b with e and c with f.

This is the idea of code:

```
    String src = "text_abc";
    String regex = "a|b|c";
    String replacement = "d|e|f";
    String replaced = src.replace(regex, replacement);
```

I don't know what regular expression I should be use in regex and replacement for do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String.replace(char, char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) for this case.

```
String src = "text_abc";
String replaced = src.replace('a', 'd')
                     .replace('b', 'e')
                     .replace('c', 'f');
```

If you insist on using regular expressions (which is a silly idea for this case, it's inefficient and unnecessarily unmaintainable), you can use a `Map` with corresponding look-up for replacement:

```
String src = "text_abc";

// Can move these to class level for reuse.
final HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", "d");
map.put("b", "e");
map.put("c", "f");
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[abc]");

String replaced = src;
Matcher matcher;
while ((matcher = pattern.matcher(replaced)).find())
    replaced = matcher.replaceFirst(map.get(matcher.group()));

// System.out.println(replaced);
```

Here is an [online code demo](http://jdoodle.com/a/cp).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do it like this?

```
String replaced = src.replace("a", "d").replace("b", "e").replace("c", "f");
```

Also note that to use regex, you need to use `replaceAll()` not `replace()`.